# Magento 2 Create Tab on product view page and show product attribute data in new tab

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-view

How to create a new tab on product view page and show product attribute data in new tab?

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension or add below file to your existing extension

Add below file at **/app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
          <block class="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Producttab" name="example.tab" template="Vendor_Modulename::customtab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
              <arguments>
                  <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your Title</argument>
              </arguments>
          </block>
      </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

Add block file at **/app/code/Vendor/Modulename/Block/Producttab.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Producttab extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $registry;


    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    private $product;

    public  function __construct (
        Template\Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getCustomData(){
        $this->product = $this->registry->registry('product');
        // I have used name attribute you can use as per your need
        return $this->product->getName();
    }

}
```

Add template at **/app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/customtab.phtml** add below code to it.

```
<div>Product Attribute Data</div>
<?php echo $block->getCustomData(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

put below code in catalog_product_view.xml inside body tag.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="shipping.delivery" template="product/view/shipping_delivery.phtml" group="detailed_info">
<arguments>
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Shipping &amp;  Delivery</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

then create phtml file in below path and load your attribute data app/design/Vendor/Theme/Magento_catalog/templates/product/view/shipping_delivery.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getShippingDelivery(), 'shipping_delivery') ?>
```

All done. Clear Cache. You can see new tab in Product detail page.

Easy and Simple way. Thanks.